# asp elements not displaying from my aspx page hosted on Amazon s3

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-s3

I have created a mail app using an aspx page. When testing on a local machine all the asp elements display correctly, I am now storing the file on an Amazon s3 server but when I go to the page none of the asp elements render I only get html elements rendering. Here is the markup from my aspx page

```
<div id="content-main">
    <div class="padding">
        <form id="policy" runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID="getpolicy" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="getpolicy_Click" Text="Start using" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="security" runat="server" />

            <h3>Message Security:</h3>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="encryptionlevel" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

            <h3>Description:</h3>
            <div id="description"></div>

            <asp:Button ID="reload" runat="server" Text="Reload" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="return false;" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This markup works when testing but when it's on the Amazon s3 server the asp elements do not display.
What have I forgotten to do?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: In what way are you storing it on amazon S3. Amazon S3 is not an asp.net web server, you can't just upload an aspx page to Amazon S3 an expect it to work. Or have you somehow got a web serfver that get's its content from Amazon S3.

Comment: I have the content stored in an S3 bucket but reading the article from the link posted by @Kapil Ghormode, thanks by the way, it looks like I'll need to put the aspx page in Amazon Web Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think more help regarding run asp.net application in amazon s3 access below URl

https://aws.amazon.com/articles/.NET/3592